# Writing to Excel File with Perl

Tags: perl, export-to-excel, perl-module

This is my first attempt and I'm trying to get the basics down of using
Excel::Writer::XLSX. I can't seem to get my script to even compile.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin
#excel::writer attempt
#allows IR-Serial-Parts tracking

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;


my $ref = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', locatime();      #create the datestamp
my $file = "$ref.xlsx";
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('$file');   #declare it outside of if loop preventing original issue.
#if(-e $file){
#       my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->open('$file');  #open existing  excel file
#}
#else{
#       my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('$file');   #open new Excel   if the date on comp has changed
#}

$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("Tracking");
$worksheet->write( 'A1', 'Hi Excel!');
```

I haven't even had to do anything yet I simply just wanted to test writing to a cell in an spreadsheet, and I can't even manage to do that. I feel like I'm making this to hard right now. Here's what the shell returns.

```
Global symbol "$worksheet" requires explicit package name at writexcel.pl         line 20.
Global symbol "$workbook" requires explicit package name at writexcel.pl line   20
.
Global symbol "$worksheet" requires explicit package name at writexcel.pl      line 21.
Execution of writexcel.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now that the original question is answered.

```
Undefined subroutine &main::locatime called at writexcel.pl line 11.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

my new error. I think it may have something to do with strftime but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `$workbook` outside of the if/else loops?

Comment: That actually fixed my error, thanks for pointing out that obvious flaw I can't believe I didn't see it. Now however I'm getting an issue with my localtime().

Comment: It is `localtime`. There is `l` missing.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil thanks! I feel utterly scatter brained today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring the `$workbook` variable outside of your loops. 
Also, as you're using `strict` you need to declare `$worksheet` using `my`:

```
use strict;
use warninigs;

my $workbook;

if(-e $file){
        $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->open($file);  
}
else{
        $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($file); 
}

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('Tracking');
$worksheet->write( 'A1', 'Hi Excel!');
```

Comment: although if i don't declare `my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('Tracking');` within my loop it causes `add_worksheet()` to be undef. I assume this is because the `$workbook` value doesn't exist outside the loop

Comment: You can do it easier by `my $method = -e $file ? 'open' : 'new'; my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->$method($file);` but unfortunatelly I didn't found `open` method in `Excel::Writer::XLSX` documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('$file');
```

This line will not make a file with the name stored in `$file` variable but file with exact name `$file`.

Comment: Thank you, I discovered this as well. Do you know of any way to name the file as the days date? Or do you think I could have just one .xlsx file and add worksheets with the localtime() as the name of the worksheet?

Comment: @HeadyGains - It's best to ask a new question if you have other problems unrelated to your original problem. If nothing else, it allows others with similar problems to easily find solutions

Comment: @fugu my apologies will do.

Answer (score 0):

Declare $workbook and $worksheet with "my" outside the loop

Refer https://github.com/AarthiRT/Excel_Writer_XLSX